Effect size/power analysis of categorical variable in multilevel model
How to decide the effect size of a categorical variable with multiple levels (e.g., three or four) in MLM? And how to calculate the power of such variables using a simulation (or other) approach?

You'd choose the effect sizes based on previous research on your field, and/or based on smallest effect size that is of interest to you. As for how to practically do this, check out the R packages simr and mixedpower.

The important part, as Sointu notes and is part of your question, is that you need to get a sense of what the previous research says the effects should be before running such analyses, and this can only be done with a literature review. This can be achieved by reading through previous meta-analyses, previously fit mixed models, or the smallest effect that you would deem "important" or "useful" in your field.
For example, perhaps if we are running a study on first and second language learners of Chinese, we know that typically second language learners perform 3 standard deviations lower than first language learners. Then we already know the differences in effects should be roughly around this difference in means, and can code it in our power analysis accordingly. But perhaps we also know that an association we are after, such as the relationship between vocab and reading, has a typical correlation around $r = .40$ for second language learners, but is typically half that in first language learners. Then again, we can include that in our simulation.
If one wants an approach that does much of the heavy lifting for you, then you can use the simr and mixedpower packages as Sointu prescribes. Indeed, the authors of the latter package have a very intuitive series of tutorials for how to run their functions for the simulations.
If one wants much more flexibility with their power analysis, running your own simulation really is the way to go. the tutorial series by Julian Quandt, finishing with mixed modeling here, is quite good for learning this. For some ideas on simulating data for such analyses, I provide an example with crossed random effects here and a simulated power analysis with a basic regression here.
Edit
Here is a worked example using four groups, but it can be quite easily extended to less or more groups.
#### Load Library ####
library(simr)

#### Create REs ####
RE1_ID <- (1:20) # number of REs (e.g. subjects)
RE2_ID <- (1:100) # number of REs (e.g. words)
NRE1 <- length(RE1_ID) # used later for sample size
NRE2 <- length(RE2_ID) # same
artificial_data <- expand.grid(RE1 = RE1_ID,
                               RE2 = RE2_ID) # combines IDs of both REs

#### Code Coefficients ####
fixed_effects <-  c(400, 200, 10, 100) # order in model summary of coefs

#### Code RE Variance ####
random_variance <- list(1, 0.50) # random intercept variance of RE1 and 2

#### Make Group Variable ####
Group <- c(rep("Group_1", (NRE1 * NRE2/4)), # RE obs / groups
           rep("Group_2", (NRE1 * NRE2/4)),
           rep("Group_3", (NRE1 * NRE2/4)),
           rep("Group_4", (NRE1 * NRE2/4))) 

#### Add Vars to Data ####
artificial_data["Group"] <- Group # add group to fake data
artificial_data["Outcome"] <- rnorm(NRE1 * NRE2) # add DV to data

#### Make "Fake" Model ####
artificial_lmer <- makeLmer(
  Outcome 
  ~ Group
  + (1 | RE1)
  + (1 | RE2),
  fixef = fixed_effects,
  VarCorr = random_variance, 
  data = artificial_data
)

#### Summarized Model ####
summary(artificial_lmer)

#### Test Power ####
power_simr <- powerSim(artificial_lmer, test= fixed("Group"))
print(power_simr) 

Which will conduct a power analysis based off the coding of the fake data and the fixed effect of group differences in means. A similar example for logistic GLMMs is shown in Notebook 3 of mixedpower, which I borrowed this example from with some modifications.

Thank you so much! As far as I know, previous research in our field typically employs standardized coefficients of MLM as the effect size (when using MLM). However, I'm feeling confused about how to handle categorical variables, as they often result in multiple coefficients. How should I calculate the effect size in this situation?

Like I mentioned above, you would code the categorical effects based off what you think the differences in means should be. For example, if we expect the mean of the control/reference group is 400 and the treatment/comparison group to be 600, then our intercept can be roughly $\beta_0 = 400$ and our slope for the comparison $\beta_1 = 200$, as this makes an "adjusted mean" from the conditional mean of the intercept. For +2 groups, you just code more adjustments for each group.

I have amended my answer to show an example based off what I said here.

Thanks a lot!!! - If I have 4 groups, is this code correct? Group <- c(rep(0, (NRE1 * NRE2/2)),
rep(1, (NRE1 * NRE2/2))
rep(3, (NRE1 * NRE2/2))
rep(4, (NRE1 * NRE2/2)))     - If I understand correctly, the coefficients can indicate the effect size of two groups (e.g., group 2 and group 1, or group 3 and group 1). But when comparing multiple groups, which type of effect size I should use in MLM? (For instance, we could use -square in ANOVA, and r-square in regression).

Note quite the right code. I edited the code I had so it includes four groups now. As far as effect sizes, this analysis would only quantify the statistical power based off the magnitudes of the individual coefficients. If you wanted to the see how the model looks based off different magnitudes of pseudo $R^2$ or other mixed modeling effect sizes, then you would probably have to hand simulate this instead to include that as part of the simulation, which is certainly a lot more complicated. I also gave the groups names, as any beyond 2 groups will just be labeled as NA in the summary.

As to what effect size you should use, there is no universal agreement there on what should be reported with respect to effects. Some use pseudo $R^2$ for model effects, some use just the raw coefficients, some use partial $R^2$, some use $f^2$...

Got it! I really appreciate your help!!
